# Convert column with mixed text values and None to integer lists efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I have a column with the values

`data = pd.DataFrame([['1,2,3'], ['4,5,6'], [None]])`

I want the output to be:

`[[1,2,3]], [[4,5,6]], [None]]`

In other words, splitting up the comma-delimited strings into lists while ignoring the None values.

This function works fine for `apply`:

```
def parse_text_vector(s):
    if s is None:
        return None
    else:
        return map(int, s.split(','))
```

As in this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1,2,3'], ['4,5,6'], [None]])
result = df[0].apply(parse_text_vector)
```

But across millions of rows, this gets quite slow. I was hoping to improve runtime by doing something along the lines of

`parse_text_vector(df.values)`, but this leads to:

```
In [61]: parse_text_vector(df.values)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-527d5f9f2b84> in <module>()
----> 1 parse_text_vector(df.values)

<ipython-input-49-09dcd8f24ab3> in parse_text_vector(s)
      4         return None
      5     else:
----> 6         return map(int, s.split(','))

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I get this to work? Or otherwise optimize this so that it doesn't take tens of minutes to process my million-line dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.str.split` and then convert to a list:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
    Col1
0  1,2,3
1  4,5,6
2   None

In [10]: df.Col1.str.split(',').tolist()
Out[10]: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], None]
```

To convert the inner list elements to integers, you can do a conversion with `map` inside a list-comprehension:

```
In [22]: [list(map(int, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in df.Col1.str.split(',').tolist()]
Out[22]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], None]
```